# How to install apt-get or yum for cmder?

Tags: apt, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have cmder installed, because I want to use the unix command line on a windows machine. I would like to install apt-get so that I can install more things using cmder.

I could also use yum

Currently I receive the following

```
λ apt-get
'apt-get' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

λ apt
'apt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

λ yum
'yum' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

`apt` is a Debian package management tool, used in Debian, of course, and its derivatives such as Ubuntu. If you want to use it in Windows I would suggest the easiest route to doing that is to install Ubuntu 20.04 from the Windows store:
[Ubuntu 20.04 WSL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/ubuntu-2004-lts/9n6svws3rx71)

To launch, use "ubuntu2004" on the command-line prompt (cmd.exe) - from within `cmdr` if you like - or click on the Ubuntu tile in the Start Menu.